# H264 PPS and SPS on Android Device

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

Using the Android Camera Video recorder I made a video:

It seems like seqParamSetLength always is 15 and picParamSetLength is always 4.

Is this somehow defined in Codec (MediaCodec)?

```
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: parseAVCCodecSpecificData
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: getNalUnitType: 103
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: parseParamSet
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: parseParamSet 67
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: getNalUnitType: 104
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: parseParamSet
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: parseParamSet 68
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: seqParamSetLength 15
03-14 20:27:30.125   379  3343 I MPEG4Writer: picParamSetLength 4
```

Want to do something similar like this below, but wonder how to set the values in the MediaCodec for seqParamSetLength and picParamSetLength? Are they per device? Per codec?

[MediaCodec configuration for SPS and PPS H264 encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023924/mediacodec-configuration-for-sps-and-pps-h264-encoder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like seqParamSetLength always is 15 and picParamSetLength is always 4.

This is not true. The size of the SPS/PPS are different depending on the encoder and settings used. Since android typically uses hardware encoders, You will get different sizes on different devices.

Comment: Are those the parameters - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat ? Wondering why on my Device camera app has 15 length for seqParamSetLength and 4 for picParamSetLength. Do you know where this could be defined?

Comment: They are defined in ISO 14496-10

Comment: SPS and PPS, embedded in the codec-private data showing up in the 'avcC' atom of an mp4 file, are emitted by the encoder and contain, well, H.264's picture parameters and stream parameters. In most cases you'll treat them as opaque because they're encoded with an intricate variable-length coding scheme. I had the need to decode them, and you can find what I did [here](https://github.com/OllieJones/h264-interp-utils), in js. But, don't try to decode them unless you must.

Comment: Thank you both. If you know Android Media and Java, opened also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645620/pps-and-sps-values-in-android-samsung-s3-neo-phone